# Windows 7 MARGINS structure in Python

Tags: python, windows-7, pywin32, aero, margins

I'm attempting to get some of the more interesting Windows Aero effects working in Python.

The **DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea** function can be used to extend the Aero glass into the client area. It requires a Window handle and a pointer to a **MARGINS** structure. I already know how to get a window's handle in Python; however, I'm unaware of how to make a margins structure.

[MARGINS structure, MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773244%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Here is what I have so far:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import string
import ctypes

root = tk.Tk()

handle = string.atoi(root.wm_frame(), 0)

dwm = ctypes.windll.dwmapi

# needs pointertomarginsstruct
dwm.DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(handel, pointertomarginsstruct)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not have Win7 running to test this but try defining the struct with ctypes:

```
class MARGINS(ctypes.Structure):
  _fields_ = [("cxLeftWidth", c_int),
              ("cxRightWidth", c_int),
              ("cyTopHeight", c_int),
              ("cyBottomHeight", c_int)
             ]
margins = MARGINS(1, 2, 1, 1)

dwm.DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(handel, ctypes.byref(margins))
```